# Why is this jQuery promise's progress callback not called during animation?

Tags: jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

This might be a newbie question on jQuery's Deferred and Promise, that in the following code

http://jsfiddle.net/mF2rn/

```
var p = $("#foo").animate({ opacity: 0 }, 2000).promise();

console.log(p);
console.log(p.constructor);
console.log($.fx.interval);

p.progress(function() {
    console.log("progress callback is invoked");
});
```

I do not see the `console.log()` output at all, which is supposedly called every 13ms during the animation which is 2 seconds.  Why and how to make it work?

**Update:** supposedly, it should work the same as http://jsfiddle.net/mF2rn/11/ which actually will print out the `console.log` output.

The code is:

```
$("#foo").animate({ 
    opacity: 0
}, { 
    progress: function() {
        console.log("progress callback is invoked");
    },
    duration: 2000
});
```

Comment: Why do you think that `promise()` triggers the `progress` callback every frame? The documentation only mentions the promise will be resolved when all the animations queued on the element will have finished.

Comment: O'Reilly has a book on jQuery Deferreds that says "jQuery calls progress callbacks every jQuery.fx.interval milliseconds on elements that are being animated"

Comment: @動靜能量: Yeah, but that's only the `progress` option callback to the `animate` function, not the progress of an installed `promise()`

Comment: the book says "`$('#something').animate({..., progress: function(){ ... })`
is equivalent to:
`$('#something').animate(...).promise().progress(function(){ ... })`"

Comment: Would you mind to cite the exact title of the book, and maybe check which version of jQuery they're using (the behaviour might've changed)?

Comment: yup, the simple "Learning jQuery Deferreds" by O'Reilly Jan 2014

Comment: also, I found that on page ix of that book, it says "This book was written for the 1.10.2 or 2.0.3 versions of jQuery"

Comment: @動靜能量 That's very interesting, it looks like you have found an error in the book and thanks to Danny Joris (is that you too?) for submitting the Errata to the O'Reilly site. I'm the person who wrote that part of the book, and I apologize for being completely wrong :-(

Comment: BTW, the proposed solution from @Anup is a good one.

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be to create a custom deferred object and use the animation's progress event handler to have the custom deferred notified about the progress. Here's the code:

**THE HTML**

```
<div class="paras">
    <p>Hello, This is my first paragraph</p>
    <p>Hello, This is my second paragraph</p>
    <p>Hello, This is my third paragraph</p>
</div>
```

**The Code**

```
var dfd = $.Deferred(),
promise = dfd.promise(),
allParas = $("div.paras p")
    .animate({
        opacity: 0.25
    }, 
    {
        duration: 2000, 
        progress: function(promise, progress, remaining) {
            dfd.notify(progress);
        }, 
        done: function(promise) { 
            dfd.resolve("Animation completed"); 
        }
    });

promise.progress(function(value) {
    console.log("PROGRESS!!! - ", value);
});
promise.then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: so I think you are probably saying what the book says is incorrect and we need to implement it for the `progress` callback to be called?

Comment: The code that you have written is correct, it's just that the deferred behind jQuery animate method is not calling the notify method behind the scenes. That's why your progress event handler is not being called.